# (JAVA) Ajuda em exercício de Ordenação (Selection Sort e Inserção)

Tags: java, algoritmo, classificação

> /*EXERCICIO: Escreva um método que ponha em ordem crescente uma sequência desordenada de *n* números inteiros. 
>   (a) Usando ordenação por **seleção**
>   (b) Usando ordenação por **inserção***/

Tentei resolver o exercício, porém estou chegando nesse resultado:
Sequência Original: 3 9 1 3 2 0 8 11 
Sequência Seleção: 0 3 1 3 2 11 8 9
Sequência Inserção: 0 1 3 2 3 8 9 11
**O que posso estar fazendo de errado?**

```
class Tres {

    public static int [] ordenaSelecao (int [] array) {
    int [] arraySelecao = array;
    int menor = arraySelecao[0];
    int posMenor = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<arraySelecao.length; i++) {
            //buscando menor elemento
            for (int j=i+1; j<arraySelecao.length; j++){
                if (menor > arraySelecao[j]) {
                menor = arraySelecao[j];
                posMenor = j;
                }

            }   

            if (arraySelecao[i] > arraySelecao[posMenor]) {
                int aux = arraySelecao[posMenor];
                arraySelecao[posMenor] = arraySelecao[i];
                arraySelecao[i] = aux;
            }

        }
        return arraySelecao;
    }


    public static int [] ordenaInsercao (int [] array) {
    int [] arrayInsercao = array;
        for (int i=1; i<arrayInsercao.length; i++){
            for (int j=i-1; j>0; j--){
                if (arrayInsercao[i]<arrayInsercao[j]) {
                    int aux = arrayInsercao[i];
                    arrayInsercao[j+1] = arrayInsercao[j];
                    arrayInsercao[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayInsercao;

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = {3,9,1,3,2,0,8,11};

        System.out.print("Sequencia Original: ");
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Sequencia Selecao: ");
        int [] arraySelecao = ordenaSelecao(array);
        for (int i=0; i<arraySelecao.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arraySelecao[i]+" ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Sequencia Insercao: ");
        int [] arrayInsercao = ordenaInsercao(array);
        for (int i=0; i<arrayInsercao.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayInsercao[i]+" ");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consertei o seu programa, eis como ficou:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Tres {
    public static int[] ordenaSelecao(int[] array) {
        int[] arraySelecao = array.clone();

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySelecao.length; i++) {
            int menor = arraySelecao[i];
            int posMenor = i;

            // Buscando o menor elemento.
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arraySelecao.length; j++) {
                if (menor > arraySelecao[j]) {
                    menor = arraySelecao[j];
                    posMenor = j;
                }
            }

            // Posicionando o menor elemento.
            if (arraySelecao[i] > arraySelecao[posMenor]) {
                int aux = arraySelecao[posMenor];
                arraySelecao[posMenor] = arraySelecao[i];
                arraySelecao[i] = aux;
            }
        }
        return arraySelecao;
    }

    public static int[] ordenaInsercao(int[] array) {
        int[] arrayInsercao = array.clone();
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayInsercao.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (arrayInsercao[j + 1] < arrayInsercao[j]) {
                    int aux = arrayInsercao[j + 1];
                    arrayInsercao[j + 1] = arrayInsercao[j];
                    arrayInsercao[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayInsercao;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayOriginal = {3, 9, 1, 3, 2, 0, 8, 11};
        System.out.println("Sequencia Original: " + Arrays.toString(arrayOriginal) + ".");

        int[] arraySelecao = ordenaSelecao(arrayOriginal);
        System.out.println("Sequencia Selecao: " + Arrays.toString(arraySelecao) + ".");

        int[] arrayInsercao = ordenaInsercao(arrayOriginal);
        System.out.println("Sequencia Insercao: " + Arrays.toString(arrayInsercao) + ".");
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/DWobC2)

O seu programa estava quase certo, os erros que haviam eram poucos e bobinhos:

- No algoritmo da seleção, você deve rastrear o menor elemento de cada iteração do `i` independente das demais iterações. Não deve rastrear no contexto da função inteira pois assim, uma vez que o menor elemento for encontrado, você fica preso nele. A solução para isso é colocar as veriáveis `menor` e `posMenor` para dentro do laço do `i` começando-as da posição `i` (e não a zero).
- No algoritmo da inserção, dentro do laço do `j`, você compara as posições `i`, `j` e `j + 1`. Você deveria usar apenas as posições `j` e `j + 1`. Além disso, a condição de parada é `j >= 0`, e não `j>0`.
- Os arrays que estão sendo passados por parâmetros são modificados e então retornados. Isso significa que no seu teste (no método `main`), o array que seria passado para a ordenação por inserção seria o array resultante da ordenação por seleção (que se estiver funcionando, já estará ordenado). O que você queria era testar a ordenação por seleção em cima de um array com o mesmo conteúdo dado à ordenação por inserção. Para fazer isso, pode-se utilizar o método `clone()` do array para criar uma cópia, evitando-se assim alterar o array original.
- Você pode usar o método [`java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) para converter os elementos do array em uma `String`, o que elimina a necessidade de imprimir elemento por elemento dele.

Comment: Não sabia que se eu escrevia .clone() em um array ele clonava automaticamente. Obrigada, entendi tudo <3